# Gärtner-Ellis theorem reference

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, large-deviation-theory

Could you please suggest a good reference for the Gärtner-Ellis theorem (at a rigorous, postgraduate student level)?
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the monograph *Large deviation techniques and applications* by Amor Dembo and Ofer Zeitouni. It contains various versions of the Gärtner-Ellis theorem (including rigorous proofs) and is highly readable.